# When computer take order to shutdown , I need to save file

Tags: windows, delphi, sleep, shutdown, delphi-xe7

How I can save the content of Listbox to file When the computer **shutting down or sleeping, or restarting** ???
I use Delphi XE7 ,

I do save the file , and I have no problem with it !

but I want to save the file when computer shutting down .

**update my code and Problem:**

my problem which is , when my project run in the background the both events OnClose & OnDestroy dose not work!

If the project work normally "not in the background", the both event's is work fine!

I figure my problem , which is my project working in background process , i add this lines to do this `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;` `Application.ShowMainForm := False;` If i make my project to run in back ground process the events `onClose` and `onDestroy` is definitely not work,

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
str :TStringList;
i : integer;
begin
  str := TStringList.Create;
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Count-1 do
    str.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);

  try
    str.SaveToFile('D:\test1.txt', TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    str.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
str :TStringList;
i : integer;
begin
  str := TStringList.Create;
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Count-1 do
    str.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);

  try
    str.SaveToFile('D:\test15.txt', TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    str.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536216

Comment: When the system shuts down, your app will be closed and you can save the file then. Likewise for restarting. I presume that you want to save the file when the app closes, rather than just when the system goes down. Sleep is different. You'll need to detect that another way.

Comment: Mr David , I try to save file , On destroy event, and On close event !
and it's didn't work !

Comment: @Adam What did you try?  Show us your code - we can't see your screen.  "Didn't work" is not very helpful.  What happened?  Did the code not compile?  Did it execute?  Were there errors?  Exceptions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I figure my problem , which is my project working in background process , i add this lines to do this `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;` 


  `Application.ShowMainForm := False;`


If i make my project to run in back ground process the events `onClose` and `onDestroy` is definitely not work,
I update my question and put mycode.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about whether or not you want the listbox to be saved when the app closes normally. I cannot understand why you would use a listbox in a non-visual app. I have not got the energy to help you work out what your question really is. Sorry.

Comment: maybe it's a mistake to use listbox , I can use TstringList to do my job,

I use listbox or stringList to delete every lines I searched for it ,
and every computer shut down I want to save the listbox or stringlist contents to file if search process not finish !

Is it clear ?? :)

Comment: Not really. I cannot understand why you are happy to let the program close without taking action, but want to do something when the system shuts down. I don't understand why you won't read MSDN docs. And I don't want to spend more time fighting.

Comment: I couldn't answer it because it was incomplete and you still didn't address all of my questions. You should be more forthcoming.

Comment: How does a user close your application normally?

Answer (score 2):

Handle the `WM_ENDSESSION` message and save your file there.

Catch the [windows message](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/aa020800a.htm) like this:

```
private
    procedure OnShutDown(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_ENDSESSION;
```

And here is your implementation

```
procedure TForm1.OnShutDown(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    //Save your file here. 
end;
```

Comment: Do you know what a windows message is? Do you know what an `if` statement is? Did you read the documentation for `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`?

Comment: @Charlie Docs say *When an application returns TRUE for this message, it receives the WM_ENDSESSION message, regardless of how the other applications respond to the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message. Each application should return TRUE or FALSE immediately upon receiving this message, and defer any cleanup operations until it receives the WM_ENDSESSION message.* In other words, don't save the file in the handler for `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. This is much more complicated than your answer implies.