# Pause Windows shutdown

Tags: windows, c++builder, shutdown

How can I pause shutdown long enough for my app? I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346571/how-to-pause-windows-shutdown/18347424#18347424), but it is for Delphi - I can't translate it to C++.

Comment: What do you mean by C++? Are you building using WinAPI, has windows in it?

Comment: @Ajay: C++Builder is the Embarcadero (formerly Borland) C++ compiler/IDE. Google it.

Comment: @KenWhite, I didn't ask that. I meant if there is a message-loop in OP's program, so that they can handle `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`

Comment: What can't you translate? What have you tried that isn't working for you? Post your efforts so far that have failed, and explain what problem you're having, including error messages you're getting, and we can try to help.

Comment: @Ajay: Of course there is. This question is about C++ Builder. It has it's own Windows wrapper framework (similar to what MS has with MFC), known as the VCL, that it shares with Delphi. If you're not familiar with either of them, you won't be able to help with this question

Comment: @KenWhite, C++ Builder is an IDE, as you yourself mentioned (assuming I was unaware). IDE doesn't define any library usage. I believe Builder allows C++ development without VCL, just like VS allows app development without MFC. Even without MFC, you can craft Windows application NOT having any UI, and not having any message loop. Even with MFC, there can be "no-UI, no-message-loop".

Comment: @Ajay: C++Builder IDE *does* in fact specify library usage; by default, all new projects are VCL-based. No one in their right mind would do Windows development in C++ Builder without using the VCL, particularly someone who can't read the API documentation for `ShutDownBlockReasonCreate`. :-) Unless the poster indicates otherwise, it's a VCL application. (And your first comment led me to believe you weren't aware ("Are you building using  WinAPI, has windows in it?". It's a Windows app using C++ Builder, so it clearly uses the WinAPI.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a C++Builder VCL translation of the Delphi code:

```
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
  ..
protected:
    void __fastcall WMQueryEndSession(TWMQueryEndSession &Message);
    ..
public:
    ..
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
        VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_QUERYENDSESSION, TWMQueryEndSession, WMQueryEndSession)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP(TForm)
};

...

void __fastcall TForm1::WMQueryEndSession(TWMQueryEndSession &Message)
{
    Message.Result = TRUE;
    if ((Message.Unused & ENDSESSION_CRITICAL) == 0)
    {
        ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(Handle, L"please wait while muting...");

        Sleep(45000); // do your work here

        ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what Message.Unused & ENDSESSION_CRITICAL are for?  I could not find documentation for them anywhere.  Thanks very much.

Comment: The `Unused` field corresponds to the `lParam` value of the [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890.aspx) message. The field is *unused* by the VCL, but it actually contains flags describing why the shutdown is taking place, where `ENDSESSION_CRITICAL` means "*The application is forced to shut down*". So, the code is blocking shutdown if the app is NOT being *forcibly* shutdown by the OS.

Comment: See [Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx), which describes why `ENDSESSION_CRITICAL` exists. It was added in Vista as part of the new shutdown API.

Comment: Thanks again Remy from the old Team B.  You've been helping me since BCB 3!

Comment: @kizeloo: TeamB is still around, still helping people in Embarcadero's [web/nntp forums](http://forums.embarcadero.com) and [community forums](http://community.embarcadero.com/forum).